# Reading from serial & saving values separately

Tags: c++, qt

Using Arduino, I print an integer and a float as below (I do it in a loop):

```
delay(500);
Serial.print(tempSensor);
delay(500);
Serial.print(LDRSensor);
```

On the other side I use Qt's 'QSerialPort' to read from serial, as below:

```
serial.setPortName("COM3");
serial.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite);
serial.setBaudRate(QSerialPort::Baud9600);
serial.setDataBits(QSerialPort::Data8);
serial.setParity(QSerialPort::NoParity);
serial.setStopBits(QSerialPort::OneStop);
serial.setFlowControl(QSerialPort::NoFlowControl);

while(!serial.isOpen()) serial.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite);

if (serial.isOpen() && serial.isWritable()){
QByteArray input, input1;

std::chrono::seconds interval(1);
for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i){        \\Read from serial for 3 seconds
    serial.waitForBytesWritten(250);
    serial.waitForReadyRead(250);
    Sleep(490);
    input = serial.readAll();       \\First value
    }


    serial.waitForBytesWritten(250);
    serial.waitForReadyRead(250);
    Sleep(490);
    input1 = serial.readAll();      \\Second value
}
```

The problem is that the "reader" sometimes reads the 'tempSensor' first, the 'LDRSensor' afterward and sometimes vice versa. Can I set 'QSerialPort' to always receive the tempSensor first and then LDRSensor so that I can separately save them in different arrays?

Comment: I think it would be better to use signals for reading. Do you know how to use them? Also I would add more information to the messages you send from Arduino so you can know which message type you just received.

Comment: I kinda understand how reading from serial using signals work, but does it make it possible to receive and save values separately?

Comment: You can if you make the messages different. But you will need to add few steps to the sending and also to the reading part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will make it very simple. You can try to do something like this on the sending side:

```
Serial.print('T');        //start of the temperature message
Serial.print(tempSensor); //temp value
Serial.print('\n');       //end of line

Serial.print('L');        //start of the LDR message
Serial.print(LDRSensor);  //LDR value
Serial.print('\n');       //end of line

delay(1000);
```

And on the receiving side:

```
while (your condition)
{
    while (serial.canReadLine())
    {
        QString message = serial.readLine();
        message = message.trimmed();     //remove the end of line character
        QString strVal = message.mid(1); //remove the first character
        int value = strVal.toInt();      //convert to int

        if (message.startsWith("T"))
        {
            // Temp received
        }
        else if (message.startsWith("L"))
        {
            // LDR received
        }
    }
    Sleep(10);
}
```

But I would definitely recommend you to not read in a cycle but use signals instead.

Comment: Thank you. Not that it solved the problem, but I also learned about trimmed(), mid() and startsWith(). And again thanks for taking time and making it simple.

Comment: @Log so you still have the problem?

Comment: Oh, my bad! I actually wanted to say that it both solved the problem and helped me learn about those functions.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say your main problem is that you aren't clarifying the data as it is being sent. I would suggest you wrap up your data into a message, with a header and checksum (though to be honest, the checksum isn't really necessary).

I would recommend sending (in this order):

- A byte to specify the total size (in bytes) of the message
- A byte to specify whether this is a temperature or LDRSensor reading
- An int containing the value of the sensor
- A byte signifying the end of message, or a checksum.

If you really wanted to keep things simple, you could forgo the first and last bytes. The message size is likely to always be 5 bytes and given it's regularity and low chances of interference, a checksum isn't really necessary.

Then all you have to do is interpret the messages as they arrive and your program will know what kind of data has arrived and how to process it. If you rely on timing alone, you are always at risk of getting out of sync.

Comment: Thanks, it gives me an idea about how reading from serial should be done properly. 
I just accepted another answer that included the code. Too bad that the new user's upvote does not publicly change the answer's score.
Thanks again.